# Title in the BottomSheet

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

I have a BottomSheet with a RecyclerView, and I want to add a title there as in the picture below ("Add new record"), I was trying to add TextView before the RecyclerView in the bottom_sheet LinearLayout, but this text doesn't appear on the screen, also I was trying to add an item in the RecyclerView (but I have a feeling that it's not a right approach), so my question is how to add the title to the BottomSheet?

This is the method where I'm adding items to the RecyclerView, which is in the BottomSheet:

```
private void showBottomSheetDialog() {
            if (behavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }

            mBottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);


            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sheet, null);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(createItems(), new ItemAdapter.ItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(Item item) {
                    if (mBottomSheetDialog != null) {
                        mBottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }));

            mBottomSheetDialog.setContentView(view);
            mBottomSheetDialog.show();
            mBottomSheetDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    mBottomSheetDialog = null;
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mAdapterItem.setListener(null);
        }

        public List<Item> createItems() {
            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.camera, "from new shoots"));
            items.add(new Item(R.drawable.folder_multiple_image, "from ready images"));
            return items;
        }
```

xml of the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#118b0a"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/float_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_white" />


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

                <!-- Here I was trying to add text view-->
                <!--<TextView-->
                <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                <!--android:text="Add new record 2"-->
                <!--/>-->


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#fff" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml of item in the RecyclerView which is in the BottomSheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#787878"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Were you able to do it?